# Why does `precise` qualifier not take effect?

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, glsl, precision

I'm trying to improve Henry Thasler's GLSL implementation of double-single arithmetic (from his GLSL Mandelbrot demo) to work reliably on NVIDIA graphics on Linux. I've recently learned that since OpenGL 4.0 (*§4.7 The Precise Qualifier* in [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.00.pdf)) or with `GL_ARB_gpu_shader5` extension ([spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader5.txt)) we can use `precise` qualifier to make the calculations follow exact sequence of arithmetic operations specified in the GLSL source.

But the following attempt appears to not give any improvement:

```c
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 : require

vec2 ds_add(vec2 dsa, vec2 dsb)
{
    precise float t1 = dsa.x + dsb.x;
    precise float e = t1 - dsa.x;
    precise float t2 = ((dsb.x - e) + (dsa.x - (t1 - e))) + dsa.y + dsb.y;

    precise vec2 dsc;
    dsc.x = t1 + t2;
    dsc.y = t2 - (dsc.x - t1);
    return dsc;
}
```

The result is the same as if there were no `precise` added. I've checked that the algorithm itself is correct: it works as is (even without `precise`) on Intel Core i7-4765T built-in graphics, and if I hide some variables to inhibit optimizations, then NVidia also gives the correct results. Here's how I inhibit the optimizations:

```c
#version 330

#define hide(x) ((x)*one)
uniform float one=1;

vec2 ds_add(vec2 dsa, vec2 dsb)
{
    float t1 = dsa.x + dsb.x;
    float e = hide(t1) - dsa.x;
    float t2 = ((dsb.x - e) + (dsa.x - (t1 - e))) + dsa.y + dsb.y;

    vec2 dsc;
    dsc.x = t1 + t2;
    dsc.y = t2 - (hide(dsc.x) - t1);
    return dsc;
}
```

So, apparently, I'm using the `precise` qualifier incorrectly. But what exactly is wrong here?

For reference, I'm using NVidia GeForce GTX 750Ti with binary nvidia driver 390.116. Here's the full C++ test:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
// glad.h is generated by the following command:
// glad --out-path=. --generator=c --omit-khrplatform --api="gl=3.3" --profile=core --extensions=
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using glm::vec4;

GLuint vao, vbo;
GLuint texFBO;
GLuint program;
GLuint fbo;
int width=1, height=2;

void printShaderOutput(int texW, int texH)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texFBO);

    std::vector<vec4> data(texW*texH);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data.data());
    std::cout << "a,b,sum,relError(sum),note\n";
    for(int i=0;i<width;++i)
    {
        const auto a=double(data[i+width*0].x)+double(data[i+width*0].y);
        const auto b=double(data[i+width*0].z)+double(data[i+width*0].w);
        const auto sum=double(data[i+width*1].x)+double(data[i+width*1].y);
        const auto trueSum=a+b;
        const auto sumErr=(sum-trueSum)/trueSum;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10)
                  << a << ',' << b << ','
                  << sum << ','
                  << std::setprecision(3)
                  << sumErr << ','
                  << (std::abs(sumErr)>1e-14 ? "WARN" : "OK")
                  << '\n';
    }
    std::cout.flush();
}

GLuint makeShader(GLenum type, std::string const& srcStr)
{
    const auto shader=glCreateShader(type);
    const GLint srcLen=srcStr.size();
    const GLchar*const src=srcStr.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, &srcLen);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    GLint status=-1;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    assert(glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR);
    assert(status);
    return shader;
}

void loadShaders()
{
    program=glCreateProgram();

    const auto vertexShader=makeShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1+R"(
#version 330
in vec4 vertex;
void main() { gl_Position=vertex; }
)");
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);

    const auto fragmentShader=makeShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1+R"(
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 : require

vec2 ds_add(vec2 dsa, vec2 dsb)
{
    precise float t1 = dsa.x + dsb.x;
    precise float e = t1 - dsa.x;
    precise float t2 = ((dsb.x - e) + (dsa.x - (t1 - e))) + dsa.y + dsb.y;

    precise vec2 dsc;
    dsc.x = t1 + t2;
    dsc.y = t2 - (dsc.x - t1);
    return dsc;
}

uniform vec2 a, b;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    if(gl_FragCoord.y<1)   // first row
        color=vec4(a,b);
    else if(gl_FragCoord.y<2)   // second row
        color=vec4(ds_add(a,b),0,0);
}

)");
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    GLint status=0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    assert(glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR);
    assert(status);

    glDetachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    glDetachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
}

void setupBuffers()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    const GLfloat vertices[]=
    {
        -1, -1,
         1, -1,
        -1,  1,
         1,  1,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof vertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    constexpr GLuint attribIndex=0;
    constexpr int coordsPerVertex=2;
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribIndex, coordsPerVertex, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribIndex);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

bool init()
{
    if(!gladLoadGL())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLAD\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(!GLAD_GL_VERSION_3_3)
    {
        std::cerr << "OpenGL 3.3 not supported\n";
        return false;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texFBO);
    glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);

    loadShaders();
    setupBuffers();

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texFBO);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA32F,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,nullptr);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,texFBO,0);
    const auto status=glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    assert(status==GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

    return true;
}

void display()
{
    const static bool inited=init();
    if(!inited) std::exit(1);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);

    glUseProgram(program);
#define SPLIT_DOUBLE_TO_FLOATS(x) GLfloat(x),GLfloat(x-GLfloat(x))
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(program,"a"),SPLIT_DOUBLE_TO_FLOATS(3.1415926535897932));
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(program,"b"),SPLIT_DOUBLE_TO_FLOATS(2.7182818284590452));
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(program,"rtWidth"),width);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    printShaderOutput(width, height);
    std::exit(0);

    glFinish();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInitContextVersion(3,3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I've been able to extract the NVfp5.0 assembly from the GLSL program binaries in the different cases:

- Naïve case without `hide` and without `precise`:

```
!!NVfp5.0
OPTION NV_internal;
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
PARAM c[2] = { program.local[0..1] };
TEMP R0;
TEMP T;
TEMP RC, HC;
OUTPUT result_color0 = result.color;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {1, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result_color0.xy, c[0];
MOV.F result_color0.zw, c[1].xyxy;
ELSE;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {2, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
ADD.F R0.y, -c[0].x, c[0].x;
ADD.F R0.x, -c[1], c[1];
ADD.F R0.x, R0, R0.y;
ADD.F R0.x, R0, c[0].y;
ADD.F R0.y, R0.x, c[1];
ADD.F R0.x, c[0], c[1];
ADD.F result_color0.x, R0, R0.y;
ADD.F result_color0.y, R0, -R0;
MOV.F result_color0.zw, {0, 0, 0, 0}.x;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
END
```

- The case with `precise` (notice that nothing changes except `.PREC` suffix in the "instructions"):

```
!!NVfp5.0
OPTION NV_internal;
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
PARAM c[2] = { program.local[0..1] };
TEMP R0;
TEMP T;
TEMP RC, HC;
OUTPUT result_color0 = result.color;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {1, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result_color0.xy, c[0];
MOV.F result_color0.zw, c[1].xyxy;
ELSE;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {2, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
ADD.F.PREC R0.y, -c[0].x, c[0].x;
ADD.F.PREC R0.x, -c[1], c[1];
ADD.F.PREC R0.x, R0, R0.y;
ADD.F.PREC R0.x, R0, c[0].y;
ADD.F.PREC R0.y, R0.x, c[1];
ADD.F.PREC R0.x, c[0], c[1];
ADD.F.PREC result_color0.x, R0, R0.y;
ADD.F.PREC result_color0.y, R0, -R0;
MOV.F result_color0.zw, {0, 0, 0, 0}.x;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
END
```

- The case with `hide`, which does work, and obviously has a different sequence of arithmetic operations:

```
!!NVfp5.0
OPTION NV_internal;
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
PARAM c[3] = { program.local[0..2] };
TEMP R0, R1;
TEMP T;
TEMP RC, HC;
OUTPUT result_color0 = result.color;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {1, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result_color0.xy, c[1];
MOV.F result_color0.zw, c[2].xyxy;
ELSE;
SLT.F R0.x, fragment.position.y, {2, 0, 0, 0};
TRUNC.U.CC HC.x, R0;
IF NE.x;
ADD.F R0.x, c[1], c[2];
MAD.F R0.y, R0.x, c[0].x, -c[1].x;
ADD.F R0.z, R0.x, -R0.y;
ADD.F R0.z, -R0, c[1].x;
ADD.F R0.y, -R0, c[2].x;
ADD.F R0.y, R0, R0.z;
ADD.F R0.y, R0, c[1];
ADD.F R0.y, R0, c[2];
ADD.F R1.x, R0, R0.y;
MAD.F R0.x, R1, c[0], -R0;
MOV.F R1.zw, {0, 0, 0, 0}.x;
ADD.F R1.y, R0, -R0.x;
MOV.F result_color0, R1;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
END
```

Comment: You may also want to try compiling your GLSL to SPIR-V, then shoving the SPIR-V shader at NVIDIA's compiler to see how it does.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used precise myself, though you may benefit from learning OpenCL or CUDA here.

In any case, your [GLSL version is 3.30, which is tied with OpenGL 3.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language). The precise qualifier is avaiable through an extension, but I would always attempt to use a built-in feature of OpenGL if you can.

The extension may not be implemented in the same manner, I suggest you try using at least GLSL version 4.0, ideally the latest OpenGL / GLSL version.

Sometimes these old extensions can have regressions on newer GPUs if no one is using them.

GPU compilers tend to be more liberal with optimizations. You may benefit from seeing the output from the compiled shader, there may be some way to view the PTX assembly output from the Nvidia compiler with GLSL.  With CUDA, you can definitely preview the assembly output to ensure the operations are not being re-ordered by the compiler.

The spec mentions MAD as being the main reason for the qualifier--it will force the compiler not to use the MAD instruction. Perhaps little testing was done with addition / subtraction with the precise qualifier.

If hide solves it for you, it's probably best to just call it a day, I doubt the precise qualifier has been thoroughly checked on the GLSL side. I highly recommend CUDA or OpenCL for this, you can use CL-GL interop if you want to display the texture quickly as well, which isn't terribly painful.

The precise qualifier ensures there is no re-ordering of operations, but doesn't mention optimizations which don't affect the ordering. It seems like AMD just turns off optimizations when using it. It's still possible that Nvidia still applies optimizations which are affecting your result which aren't related to the order of operations but rather to specific optimizations to addition being performed.

```
precise float t1 = dsa.x + dsb.x;
precise float e = t1 - dsa.x;
```

This will probably compute `e` as simply `dsb.x`. The compiler may potentially still be adding optimizations which don't affect the order of operations, as that's all that the spec guarantees. I can't think of anything other than the operations being re-ordered that would affect this result, but I'm no expert here.

Another thing to note is that based on my cursory reading of the spec, the result from the ds_add may need to be stored into a precise variable as well in order for the computation to be precise. The function may be inlined only on Nvidia (they have much better optimizations, at least historically), so I imagine that the compiler may perform the inlining and then if you store the result into a non-precise variable then all the existing precise qualifiers are ignored.

Comment: Requesting OpenGL 4.5 context with `#version 450` shaders doesn't change the situation as compared to using the extension.

Comment: I was able to extract the internal `!!NVfp5.0` sources generated by the driver for the three cases: [with `hide`](https://pastebin.com/raw/iXAYcRqk), [simple case without `hide`](https://pastebin.com/raw/QWwvj1cS), [simple case with `precise`](https://pastebin.com/raw/9kGzpisw). I can see the `.PREC` suffix on the instructions, while the sequence is the same as in the case without both `precise` and `hide`. But, this ARB/NV "assembly" doesn't actually represent the instruction sets of modern GPUs well. Anyway, it seems the `precise` doesn't influence GLSL optimizer, only NVfp translator.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing wrong with your shader. The ds_add() code just haven't any operation that could be merged at the compilation time. Usually add and multiply/divide merge. But your code have add operations only.

Update:

1. In the case all your variables are stored in GPU registers during calculation process. Order of operations for registers doesn't depend on code or compiler. It doesn't even depend on just hardware. It depends on currently running operations in the GPU.
2. Precision of floating point operations between registers isn't strictly 32 bit. It usually higher then. The actual precision for GPUs is a commercial secret. The actual precision for x86 FPU is 80 bit or 128 bit, despite the variables are stored in 32 bit memory.
3. However GPUs are not designed for very precise calculation. The algorithm's author knows it and implements double thought pairs of 32-bit floats. If you need to advance precision, then you have to use long double with quads of 32-bit floats. Simple 'precise' doesn't help.

Comment: The description in the specifications, although it does use `fma` as an example of a thing prohibited by the qualifier, doesn't seem to limit the behavior of `precise` to avoiding `fma` only: it prescribes: _"The qualifier `precise` will ensure that operations contributing to a variable's value are done in their stated order and are done with operator consistency. Order is determined by operator precedence and parenthesis, as described in section 5.1 “Operators”."_ This implies that addition and subtraction are also taken into consideration.

Comment: Yes. But just addition and subtraction are commutative and don't change precision.

Comment: So do you think addition and subtraction of floating-point numbers are associative? How about `-1 + 1 + 1e-10` vs `-1 + (1 + 1e-10)`? The former is `1e-10`, while the latter is `0` with 32-bit `float`. This is exactly the problem I'm trying to fix by the appropriate use of `precise`.

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect [with respect to the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#the-precise-qualifier). While it allows commutative transformations, it does not allow associative transformations. And presumably, that includes the computation of intermediate values.

Comment: Any CPU/GPU/FPU actually has two precision - external and internal. External precision is for loading/unloading values. Internal one is for calculating. This systems is developed literally for solving the case. Internal precision sometimes is commercial secret (GPUs), sometimes isn't (Intel/AMD CPUs). But internal precision is significantly greater then external.

Comment: But if you need to have precision upto 1e-10, you shouldn't use GPUs at all. They aren't designed for the task.

Comment: @NicolBolas Only very old i386 FPUs respected order of floating point operations. All modern CPUs/GPUs don't preserve it.

Comment: @AndreyChistyakov that's wrong. All modern CPUs and GPUs preserve the order. Only out-of-order execution can sort of not preserve the order, but the observable result is still guaranteed to be as if the order were the same. The only entities which fail to preserve the order are the compilers, and even among C compilers most do provide options to be standard-compliant (e.g. `-fno-unsafe-math-optimizations` on gcc, which is on by default).

Comment: Also, speaking of x87, you are very out of date. x86_64 CPUs (which virtually all modern x86 CPUs are) guarantee support for SSE2, which has means to work with exactly `float32` and `float64` data types (there's no means for x87 long double format in SSE2, but x87 instruction set is still present and usable even in native 64-bit mode).

Comment: SSE2 inside 64 for 32 bit floats

Comment: " but x87 instruction set is still present and usable even in native 64-bit mode). " They are not accessable in 64-bit address mode

Comment: _"They are not accessable in 64-bit address mode"_ — just look at this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GGFWju If these instructions weren't accessible, clang wouldn't be able to generate them for x86_64 target. You seem to be confusing what Microsoft compilers do (not support 80-bit float) with what the CPU allows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194248/discussion-between-andrey-chistyakov-and-ruslan).